# not able to retrieve a simple xml node value in html

Tags: html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have the following xml code in a document called `note.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and i have the following html code in a file called sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>

<div>
<b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br />
<b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br />
<b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","C:\Users\cxpv2\Desktop\IV\New folder\Test Game descriptions\attempt test game1\note.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

This example is directly taken from w3schools.com
The node values in the above xml are not being displayed in the html document. Should i change the name of the html file or let me know if this is the right way to display the xml content in a html file.

I changed the

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml",false);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","C:\Users\cxpv2\Desktop\IV\New folder\Test Game descriptions\attempt test game1\note.xml",false);
```

mentioning the whole exact location

## Update

Let me know if iam doing it right atleast. I will ask my sysadmin if there is something wrong with activexobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use XMLHttpRequest to make a local request as it would be security vulnerability to let a script read files from your local machine.

If you open the error console in your browser chances are you will see the error printed there.

Comment: I'm not able to open the developer tools or error console. Im using IE8, and nothing happens when i hit f12. Thank you for the answer anyway. I think the problem is that i'm not having rights on this browser. I will check this at home in my laptop.

Comment: It really does not make any difference on what computer you try to do this. The browser will never allow it due to the potential security risk.

Comment: how do i solve this problem? i cannot even open and see my error log here

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? How will the page be used? Any specific reason as to why you are using XMLHttpRequest?It is not clear what the problem you are trying to solve is from your question.

Comment: i wanted to test [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_parsertest) and hence the xml file 'note.xml' is from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml) link. I created both the files note.xml and sample.html and tried to open the html file so that i can see the node values in html page

Comment: The reason it works on that link is because both files are accessed using the http-protocol and are on the same domain. Those are the security requirement for using the XMLHttpRequest object.When testing locally you are using the file-protocol and are subject to other security restrictions. Consider the potential harm that could come from downloading a .htm file from the internet that once run would access and upload sensitive data from your computer to a third-party. That is the reason for the security restriction which stops you from using XMLHttpRequest to read local files.

Comment: how can i avoid this? should i just remove the httprequest and write document.getElementByTagName? please let me know how to call this note.xml file in the sample.html file so that i can display the nodes in the html file

Comment: thanks i got what you are saying. I found [this](http://www.steveborn.com/codenotes/LoadingXML.htm)  link

Comment: No problem. If you want to do this with html/xml on your local computer (eg. not using a web server and http) you would be better off looking into XSLT: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp